# How do I update the typescript compiler on my heroku server?

Tags: typescript, heroku

My typescript project will not build on my heroku server.

```
-----> Build
       Running build

       > back-end@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_32c5a59b6806145803516c50f84fc693
       > tsc && node build/index.js

       error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'esModuleInterop'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! back-end@1.0.0 build: `tsc && node build/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the back-end@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.DGTha/_logs/2019-07-27T07_56_31_141Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

I am able to build and run the app locally. My local version of tsc is 3.5.1

But on my heroku bash I get this.

```
~ $ tsc -v
message TS6029: Version 1.5.3
```

Even though my package.json on heroku looks like this:

```
~ $ cat package.json
{
  "name": "back-end",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "precompile": "rimraf build",
    "compile": "tsc && node build/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch src/ --exec \"npm run compile\" --verbose -e ts",
    "start": "tsc && node build/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.5",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.2",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.5.11",
    "@types/node": "^12.6.8",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.33",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "mixer-client-node": "^2.7.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-mixer": "^1.0.1",
    "tsc": "^1.20150623.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "ws": "^7.0.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "plugins": [
      "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "extends": [
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
      "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "@typescript-eslint/indent": [
        "error",
        2
      ],
      "linebreak-style": 0
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.13.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.3",
    "eslint-watch": "^4.0.2",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Notice `"tsc": "^1.20150623.0"`. This is the exact same as my local package.json as you would expect.

But when I run `tsc -v` on my local machine I get this:

```
> tsc -v

Version 3.5.3
```

I have tried fixing this by running `npm uninstall -g tsc` and then reinstalling through heroku bash. This did not fix the problem.

Why is the tsc version so outdated on my heroku server? Why is tsc installed globally by default? (I have to use npm scripts to check the version on my machine). How do I update tsc on heroku and fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, you probably already have installed tsc globally, which will ignore what you have defined in your package.json. To specifically use the one you installed in your project try running

`npx tsc -v`

This will use your locally installed typescript and tsc. Of course, you can use `npx tsc` to compile your project with the tsc version you specified in your package.

Comment: This is helpful (I did not know about the npx command), but it did not solve my problem.

`npx tsc -v` still says `message TS6029: Version 1.5.3` and my project does not compile when changing the npm build script to have `npx tsc`

Keep in mind, this issue is only present on my heroku server

Answer (score 0):

[`tsc` doesn't seem to be an NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=tsc), so you can probably remove it entirely. It's just a confusion at the moment. I think you want [`typescript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) instead.

You do have `typescript` in your `package.json`, but it's listed under *`devDependencies`*, not `dependencies`. By default [you can't use `devDependencies` at runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation):

> After running the installation and [build steps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#heroku-specific-build-steps) Heroku will strip out the packages declared under `devDependencies` before deploying the application.

If you really need `tsc` at runtime move it to `dependencies`.

Comment: You are correct! I found this out, and I will update my question. However, I have tried moving Typescript to the dependencies and that did not fix the issue. I made it so that  `tsc` is run in the build script, so it shouldn't make a difference. Still having this issue where on my heroku server, Typescript is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was doing wrong.

First of all, `tsc` is not a valid npm module, do not install it.

Instead, the tsc bash command comes from the `typescript` module.

If you are having issues with the version of your npm modules on your heroku server, try disabling node_modules cache

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#cache-behavior

This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced some issues when I deployed my React project using TypeScripts. So I found a way to resolve my issues is using Webpack. The Webpack will make a main.js file from your Typescript files, so Heroku can know what you deployed.

You can find more information here: [enter link description here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/)